# ffmpeg insert black to video head/tail

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I tried to carry out the matter of the title.

`ffmpeg -i "${in}" -vf tpad=5,start_duration=5,color=black -af adelay=5s,all=1 "${out}"`

Console Error:

```sh
Only '-vf tpad=5,start_duration=5,color=black' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-af adelay=5s,all=1' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters


No such filter: 'all'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

I can hardly understand this legacy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Always test the ffmpeg command before you integrate it into a script. Use are using commas (`,`) instead of colons (`:`). Use:

```
ffmpeg -i "${in}" -vf "tpad=5:start_duration=5:color=black" -af "adelay=5s:all=1" "${out}"
```